# Getting Permission Denied Error When I push to remote ( Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists)

Tags: git, github, push

I cloned another person's repository. I was able to add and commit a file in my local copy of the repository. When I try to execute a "git push" command however I am getting an error message.

My git hub username is Nikola901. The user that I am getting the repository from is mqttbroker

here are the commands I executed: 
[image: successful commands]

the last command is what fails but I cannot seem to figure out why:
[image: permission error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have push permissions for the other user's repository.

Try forking the repository to make your own copy of it, and then clone your fork onto your machine.

You should then `git push` any changes you make up to your fork, and then open a Pull Request to get your changes reviewed and merged back into the other user's repository.

Comment: Hey there , that’s what I’m doing but it’s not working

Comment: Did you click "Fork" on GitHub? You need to clone your own copy of the repo instead of the other person's repo. Notice that `git remote -v` is showing the other user's repository and not a copy under your account.

Comment: FYI, I did click fork

Comment: Once you've cloned your fork, you should see something like `git://github.com/Nikola901/Testbed` when you run `git remote -v`

Comment: you are absolutely right, I cloned the original repository (mqttbroker/Testbed)  instead of the one resulting from the fork . ( Nikola901/Testbed). Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.